# Plotting from concatenated files in python3

Tags: python

I have a python script to plot wrf model output (RH, Temperature, wind barbs and stremlines). The script works fine for a hourly files. I am trying to adapt the script to loop over several hours. I know one can read multifile input in python, but this works for netcdf classic.
Therefore I have to concatenate hourly files for 1 day (25 files), 2 days (49 files), etc., using nco or cdo along the time domain. I have a module1 where the reading of the variables is done. A part of this module is shown below. The module has other defined functions which I have not included. The main script imports the variable reading module.

### module to read variables

```
def main(filename):
#This function details reading in the lat, lon, u,v

    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(filename,'r')

    #Get the horizontal grid
    LAT = ncfile.variables['XLAT'][:]
    LON = ncfile.variables['XLONG'][:]

    #Get some variables
    U = ncfile.variables['U'][:]*1.94384
    V = ncfile.variables['V'][:]*1.94384

    return LAT,LON,U,V

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = '/home/zmumba/DA/OUTPUT/2022081900/noda/wrfout_d01_2022-08-19_00'
    LAT,LON,RH,U,V = main(filename)
```

When I run the above module as a python script, with say, print(U.shape) it prints the shapes ok.

Part of the main script is given below.

```
#Import libraries      
################################
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from read_module1 import *

# Read in the file using the module1 script  
#################################
#Note the file location
filename = netCDF4.Dataset('/home/zmumba/DA/OUTPUT/2022081900 /noda/wrfout_d01_2022-08-19_00',mode='r')
LAT,LON,RH,U,V = main(filename)
```

When I run it the last line gies the error

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: b"<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>\nroot group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):\n    TITLE:  OUTPUT FROM WRF V4.3.3 MODEL\n    START_DATE: 2022-08-19_00:00:00\n    SIMULATION_START_DATE: 2022-08-19_00:00:00\n ..." (all the variables given as part of this error or long file name).
```

The same line "LAT,LON,RH,U,V = main(filename)" runs fine for hourly files. Obviously this error must be coming because of concatenated files.
I am wondering if there is a solution to this. If yes, or if someone has an alternative solution, I will appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You can't pass an opened `netCDF4.Dataset` as filename to open it again. You need to open it *either* in the main script *or* inside the `main` function, not both.

Comment: Very good hint. I will work in that direction.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the comment from mkrieger1. In the module I have a line " ncfile.close() #Close the file" which I did not include in the code above. So the error has nothing to do with netCDF4.Dataset being open in two locations. The error is about the filename being too long. The same script runs perfectly with files which are not concatenated, only that these are hourly files with only one time step.